# Assign an object parameter value without $

Tags: powershell

In some cases, it would be more convenient for me to assign parameters for objects excluding $, and using the name of the object. That is, as usual:

```
$Comment = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Comment.Text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

All is well. But the next method does not work. This method cannot be assigned "Stack Overflow" to an object:

```
$Comment = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
(Set-Variable -Name Comment).Text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

Why do I need this? Because I want to select an object by name (string), and not with $. Please tell me how you can assign text (or other parameters) without assigning directly, but through the name of the object? thanks

Comment: `$((Get-Variable -Name Comment).Value).Text = 'Stack Overflow'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get-Variable` to retrieve variable contents in combination with the member access operator `.` to update a property.

```
(Get-Variable -Name Comment).Value.Text = 'Stack Overflow'
```

Since `Get-Variable` returns a `PSVariable` object with its own properties, you must access the `Value` property of that object first, which contains the value of `$Comment`. This can easily be done by surrounding the command in parentheses `()`. With this method, the value of object `$Comment` is retrieved first before applying the member access operation to property `Text`.